# What is the Proper Formula for Converting a Quaternion to a Matrix

Tags: c, 3d, opengl-3

I am currently writing my own game engine and I am having trouble properly implementing quaternions. My current quaternion implementation looks like this:

```c
/*
CybRender - Quaternion API
*/

#include "CybQuat.h"


//Functions
//=================================================================================
void Cyb_QuatFromAxisAndAngle(Cyb_Vec4 *quat, float x, float y, float z,
    float angle)
{
    quat->x = x * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->y = y * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->z = z * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->w = cosf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
}


void Cyb_MulQuat(Cyb_Vec4 *c, const Cyb_Vec4 *a, const Cyb_Vec4 *b)
{
    c->x = a->w * b->x + a->x * b->w + a->y * b->z - a->z * b->y;
    c->y = a->w * b->y - a->x * b->z + a->y * b->w + a->z * b->x;
    c->z = a->w * b->z + a->x * b->y - a->y * b->x + a->z * b->w;
    c->w = a->w * b->w - a->x * b->x - a->y * b->y - a->z * b->z;
}


void Cyb_QuatToMatrix(Cyb_Mat4 *mat, const Cyb_Vec4 *quat)
{
    //Start with the identity matrix
    Cyb_Identity(mat);
    
    //Row 1
    mat->a = 1 - 2 * quat->y * quat->y - 2 * quat->z * quat->z;
    mat->b = 2 * quat->x * quat->y - 2 * quat->w * quat->z;
    mat->c = 2 * quat->x * quat->z + 2 * quat->w * quat->y;
    
    //Row 2
    mat->e = 2 * quat->x * quat->y + 2 * quat->w * quat->z;
    mat->f = 1 - 2 * quat->x * quat->x - 2 * quat->z * quat->z;
    mat->g = 2 * quat->y * quat->z + 2 * quat->w * quat->x;
    
    //Row 3
    mat->i = 2 * quat->x * quat->z - 2 * quat->w * quat->y;
    mat->j = 2 * quat->y * quat->z - 2 * quat->w * quat->x;
    mat->k = 1 - 2 * quat->x * quat->x - 2 * quat->y * quat->y;
}
```

It works properly if I only rotate around the X, Y, or Z axis. However, when I try to rotate around an arbitrary axis, I get odd distortion:

[image]

I have tried different formulas for converting my quaternion to a matrix, but every time I get similar distortion. I already tested my matrix implementation  to make sure it was working correctly and found no problems with it.

What is the correct formula for converting a quaternion to a matrix?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a minor mistake in the function that converts a quaternion to a matrix. Here is the corrected code:

```c
/*
CybRender - Quaternion API
*/

#include "CybQuat.h"


//Functions
//=================================================================================
void Cyb_QuatFromAxisAndAngle(Cyb_Vec4 *quat, float x, float y, float z,
    float angle)
{
    quat->x = x * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->y = y * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->z = z * sinf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
    quat->w = cosf(radians(angle) / 2.0f);
}


void Cyb_MulQuat(Cyb_Vec4 *c, const Cyb_Vec4 *a, const Cyb_Vec4 *b)
{
    c->x = a->w * b->x + a->x * b->w + a->y * b->z - a->z * b->y;
    c->y = a->w * b->y - a->x * b->z + a->y * b->w + a->z * b->x;
    c->z = a->w * b->z + a->x * b->y - a->y * b->x + a->z * b->w;
    c->w = a->w * b->w - a->x * b->x - a->y * b->y - a->z * b->z;
}


void Cyb_NormalizeQuat(Cyb_Vec4 *quat)
{
    float magnitude = sqrt(quat->x * quat->x + quat->y * quat->y + quat->z * quat->z + quat->w * quat->w);
    quat->x /= magnitude;
    quat->y /= magnitude;
    quat->z /= magnitude;
    quat->w /= magnitude;
}


void Cyb_QuatToMatrix(Cyb_Mat4 *mat, const Cyb_Vec4 *quat)
{
    //Start with the identity matrix
    Cyb_Identity(mat);
    
    //Row 1
    mat->a = 1.0f - 2.0f * (quat->y * quat->y + quat->z * quat->z);
    mat->b = 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->y - quat->w * quat->z);
    mat->c = 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->z + quat->w * quat->y);
    
    //Row 2
    mat->e = 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->y + quat->w * quat->z);
    mat->f = 1.0f - 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->x + quat->z * quat->z);
    mat->g = 2.0f * (quat->y * quat->z - quat->w * quat->x);
    
    //Row 3
    mat->i = 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->z - quat->w * quat->y);
    mat->j = 2.0f * (quat->y * quat->z + quat->w * quat->x);
    mat->k = 1.0f - 2.0f * (quat->x * quat->x + quat->y * quat->y);
}
```

I hope this will help other people who need to implement quaternions.